# React-Redux: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux world and I'm trying to connect it with React. 
I have structured my app in next way:

**index.js:**

```
const userReducer = (state={
  name: "max"
}, action) => {

  switch(action.type){
    case "SET_NAME":
      state = {
        ...state,
        name: action.payload
      };
    break;
  return state;
};

const myLogger= (store) =>(next)=>(action)=>{
  console.log("logged action: ",action);
  next(action);
};
const store = createStore(combineReducers({user: userReducer}),{}, applyMiddleware(myLogger,logger));

store.subscribe(()=>{
  console.log("Store upadated", store.getState());
});

ReactDOM.render(

   <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,

    window.document.getElementById('container'));
```

**app.js:**

```
class App extends React.Component{

      render(){
        return(

        <div>
         <SearchBar
           username = {this.props.user.name}/>
        </div>
       )
      }  
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return{
        user: state.user,
        math: state.math
      };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return{
        setName: (name) =>{
            dispatch({
                type: "SET_NAME",
                payload: name
            });
        }
      };
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**searchBar.js:**

```
export default class SearchBar extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                Name: {this.props.username}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

It seems like `name` variable from `userReducer` is not recognized while I am trying to pass it to `SearchBar` component.

I am not sure why? Did I maybe structured my `index.js` wrong by trying to use `Provider` to provide store? Or maybe is it something wrong with my connect function?

ERROR:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at component (app.js:141)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:8574)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8978)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:11814)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:11843)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:11318)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:11885)
```

Comment: what is your initial `state` ?

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii `state={
  name: "max",
  age: 27
}`

Comment: oh sorry missed that. Does your code throws error after you dispatch your action ?

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii yes, it can't recognize the variable name. I thought it's maybe my structure in app or just connect function

Comment: you're mapping `state.user` to `this.props.user`, this doesn't exist in your state. So when you try to get `this.props.user.name`, `this.props.user` is null / undefined so it has no `name` attribute

Comment: @Jamie-FenrirDigitalLtd True, so how in your opinion should I map it? I am thinking the same, from that my conclusion was that is not connected god.

Comment: @user9347049 according to your comment above, the name exists on `state.name`, so in your `mapStateToProps`, map it to that... `name: state.name,`. Then, in the top of `app.js`, you render it as `<SearchBar username={this.props.name} />`

Comment: @Jamie-FenrirDigitalLtd I have tried it. Now I don't have error but name is not displayed also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should work, or maybe your imports are wrong, the only thing I see missing is the bracket:

```
switch(action.type) {
  case "SET_NAME":
    state = {
      ...state,
      name: action.payload
    };
    break;
  }
  return state;
}
```

And I think your Provider should wrap the Router too.
But at the moment, that should not be blocking.

You can also use redux dev tools (browser extension) to see where does the problem come from :

To use it add this lines to index.js:

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(combineReducers({user: userReducer}), composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(myLogger)));
```

Comment: The bracket is there I just copied it wrong. :/ I will look at my imports

Comment: As copy/past, your code is working for me, name is well displayed, and if I dispatch a new name, new name is displayed as well

Comment: Can you copy/paste your imports please. I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: index.js : 
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import App from **your_path_to_app.js**;

app.js : 
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import SearchBar from  **your_path_to_searchBar.js**;

searchBar : 
import React from 'react';

Comment: I am also sure that my code should work but can't figure what is happening

Comment: Here is my update on error I am getting, please check my question.

Comment: You were right my imports were not okay. I also wrapped Router with my Provider and now it works just fine. Tnx mate!

Answer (score 0):

In redux ... you **never alter** the original copy of state ... you need to return a new copy with each action executed.

And you also need to return an initial value before executing any actions ... thought your `switch default case` ... for redux store initialization on app load

```
const userReducer = (
      state = {
        name: 'max',
      },
      action,
    ) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_NAME':
          return {
            ...state,
            name: action.payload,
          };

        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

Comment: But isn't it variable `name` sent like `<SearchBar username={this.props.user.name}/>} `  in searchBar component as `props.username`? And not `user.props.name`?

Comment: Yes, and when I access it like `this.props.user.name` my name `variable` is `undefined` like it's never there in `user.props`. And if I try your way it's not working. I believe I have to try display it in searchBar component as                  
 `{this.props.username}`